# How can I detect which driver my bios is running on with Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-9.10, bios

I just got off the phone with an ACER support technician and he says I should make sure I have the latest BIOS driver (the installation of which could solve my overheating problems...) He helped me find [the driver](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/BIOS/BIOS/BIOS_Acer_1.11_A_A.zip?acerid=633942220264081504&Step1=Notebook&Step2=Aspire&Step3=Aspire%205536&OS=V10&LC=en&BC=Acer&SC=PA_7) and I have it downloaded as a .zip file. Now I need to know which driver I have installed for the BIOS. How do I check that on Ubuntu 9.10 - Karmic Koala?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to superuser.com.

Comment: `!programming_related ?? Response.Redirect("http://superuser.com");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of luck you can see that with `lshw`. For my system I see the motherboard version and bios version in the core->firmware section.

However... if you can't see it there than it should still be visible somewhere in the bios or when booting the system. Also, the bios upgrade utility will most likely show you the version before giving you the option to upgrade.